# How to specify a message or tag within a transaction

Tags: transaction, iota-network, microtransaction, wallet.rs

I would like to create transaction using `IotaWallet` of [wallet.rs](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs) containing a message or tag.

Currently I perfectly create a transaction for Alice wallet, using:

```
from iota_wallet import IotaWallet

# This example sends a transaction.

wallet = IotaWallet('./alice-database', client_options)

account = wallet.get_account('Alice')

# Sync account with the node
response = account.sync()
print(f'Synced: {response}')

wallet.set_stronghold_password("some_hopefully_secure_password")

options = {
        "message": "abc",
        #OR
        "tag": "abc"
}

outputs = [{
        "address": "tst1qprutadk4uc9rp6h7wh7sech42sl0z40ztpgyygr5tf0cn5jrqshg80juhm",
        "amount": "1"
}]


transaction = account.send_micro_transaction(outputs, options)
#OR
#transaction = account.send_amount(outputs, options)

print(f'Sent transaction: {transaction}')
```

But there is no trace of "Message" or "Tag" related to the created transaction in the IOTA explorer or starting from `account.transacations()` or `account.pending_transactions()`  methods.

In [documentation examples](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/how_tos/outputs_and_transactions/send_transaction/) I don't find anything.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
outputs = [{
    "address": "rms1qqvnuxck92uwvf2hjpr0m9m0rj565efvchcy0xj9u5w8cwprqealva8g48e",
    "amount": "42600",
}]

tag = '0x'+'custom_tag'.encode('utf-8').hex()
data = '0x'+'custom_data'.encode('utf-8').hex()

transaction = account.send_amount(outputs, options={"taggedDataPayload": {"type": 5, "tag": tag, "data": data}})
```

This will create a block with a tagged payload.
I created the example transaction: https://explorer.shimmer.network/testnet/transaction/0xb04a92b0e8bc52a4a2d85dd538f23c2201aa899d554428925f3ddf94b72a30ee?tab=Payload

And in the related block: https://explorer.shimmer.network/testnet/block/0xa0a69edc125eef56775185cd55a8ef9d96264d79f996047eff8e410aedee3b2b

you can find the added tagged data payload

Comment: Thank you so much Dr. Electon! Your solution is correctly working. Where can I find any reference about that please? In particular ```"type": 5```.

Comment: The payload types are documented in the TIPs: https://wiki.iota.org/tips/tips/TIP-0024/#payloads

But you shouldn't need to know that, that's why we are working on improving the DX there in a future release

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, but please note that tag is not indexed by the core API anymore:

1. You can write something like this: `sendMicroTransaction(outputs, transactionOptions)`. [Reference Wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/references/nodejs/classes/Account/#sendmicrotransaction). You can add `taggedatapayload` to `transactionOptions` and it should tag it. [Example in Explorer](https://explorer.shimmer.network/testnet/block/0xeb43ff430be12c09fc11bca1bca2c30947322a31d99bc5f719f1786863f635c2). Read more about [TransactionOptions on wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/references/nodejs/interfaces/TransactionOptions/).
2. With Stardust, you can also add data to the outputs now.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but Python [Reference Wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/references/python/iota_wallet/account/) is less simple than yours attached in Node.js. There is not a TransactionOptions interface, but just a parameter and it doesn't work.

Comment: It should ideally be same with [options](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/references/python/iota_wallet/account/#send_micro_transaction). If it's not working, please raise an issue in [wallet.rs](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/issues) repo.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Java bindings and wanted to use the TaggedDataPayload. I am a bit confused, how I would set the type. Can you please help me out?

```
public TaggedDataPayload(String tag, String data) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.data = data;
}
```

https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/blob/46f3818ffe1a8552c732379e971010fe07987506/wallet/bindings/java/lib/src/main/java/org/iota/types/payload/TaggedDataPayload.java#L5

Answer (score 0):

I built the Java library with an adjusted TaggedDataPayload:

```
package org.iota.types.payload;

public class TaggedDataPayload extends Payload {
    private int type;
    private String tag;
    private String data;

    public TaggedDataPayload(int type, String tag, String data) {
        this.type = type;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return this.tag;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I then made the transaction containing the tag and data:

```
public void makeShimmerTransaction(String receiverAddress, String amount) throws WalletException, InitializeWalletException {
        if (wallet == null) {
            log.error("Wallet has not been initialized");
            throw new InitializeWalletException("Wallet has not been initialized");
        }

        AccountHandle account = wallet.getAccount(new AccountAlias(ACCOUNT_NAME));
        account.syncAccount(new SyncAccount().withOptions(new SyncOptions()));

        AddressWithMicroAmount addressWithMicroAmount = new AddressWithMicroAmount();
        addressWithMicroAmount.withAddress(receiverAddress).withAmount(amount).withExpiration(86400);

        String tag = "0x" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary("custom_tag".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String data = "0x" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary("custom_data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        TaggedDataPayload taggedDataPayload = new TaggedDataPayload(5,tag, data);

        TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transactionOptions.withTaggedDataPayload(taggedDataPayload);

        try {
            Transaction transaction = account.sendMicroTransaction(new org.iota.types.account_methods.SendMicroTransaction().withAddressesWithMicroAmount(new AddressWithMicroAmount[]{addressWithMicroAmount}).withOptions(transactionOptions));
            log.info("Transaction successfully sent");
        } catch (Exception error) {
            log.error(String.valueOf(error));
        }
    }
```